# Derive no. at risk and n.events from weighted survfit

Tags: r, survival-analysis

————————POSSIBLY SOLVED?

I recently asked why the no. at risk is different in weighted Kaplan-Meier.
That's because it is the sum of the weights in `treat == 1` and `treat == 0`.

Data and approach:

```
library(survival)
library(cobalt)

# Fake data
set.seed(123)
options(scipen=999)
lalonde <- cbind(lalonde,
                 event = sample(c(0,1), size=614, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.84,0.16)),
                 time = runif(614, min=10, max=365))

formula <- treat ~ age + educ + race + married + nodegree + re74 + re75 + re78

#PS
lalonde$pscore <- glm(formula, data = lalonde,
                                family = binomial(link = "logit"))$fitted.values

# Calculate weights
lalonde$weight <- ifelse(lalonde$treat == 1,
                     pmin(lalonde$pscore, 1 - lalonde$pscore) / lalonde$pscore,
                     pmin(lalonde$pscore, 1 - lalonde$pscore) / (1 - lalonde$pscore))

surv_object <- Surv(time = lalonde$time, event = lalonde$event)
fit1 <- survfit(surv_object ~ treat, data = lalonde, robust = TRUE, weights = lalonde$weight)
```

To derive the no. at risk we can calculate:

```
treated1 <- sum(lalonde$weight[lalonde$treat == 1])
treated0 <- sum(lalonde$weight[lalonde$treat == 0])
```

which is nearly the same as first line of `summary(fit1)`
which gives 109 for the untreated and 110 for the treated.

Calculating the number of events for treated and untreated would be the sum of the weights for the treated/untreated who had an event, correct?

```
treated0_event <- sum(lalonde$ow[lalonde$treat == 0 & lalonde$event == 1])
treated1_event <- sum(lalonde$ow[lalonde$treat == 1 & lalonde$event == 1])
```

Is it possible to pull these values from survfit?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea. Tidy data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom) # Converting model results into a tidy data frame using the tidy() function.

fit1.tab <- tidy(fit1)

summary_data <- fit1.tab %>%
  group_by(strata) %>%
  filter(strata %in% c('treat=0', 'treat=1')) %>%
  summarize(max_n.risk = max(n.risk), sum_n.event = sum(n.event))
```

But is the calculation of events right?

Comment: `tidy()` is exported from `{broom}`, please make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be achieved without any additional package:

```
df <- data.frame(
  type = as.factor(c(names(fit1$strata))),
  max.n.risk = c(max(fit1$n.risk[1L:fit1$n[[1L]]], na.rm = TRUE), 
                  max(fit1$n.risk[fit1$n[[1L]] + 1L:length(fit1$n.risk)], na.rm = TRUE)),
  sum.n.event = c(sum(fit1$n.event[1L:fit1$n[[1L]]], na.rm = TRUE),
                   sum(fit1$n.event[fit1$n[[1L]] + 1L:length(fit1$n.event)], na.rm = TRUE))
  )
```

gives

```
> df
     type max.n.risk sum.n.event
1 treat=0   108.9441    14.88265
2 treat=1   110.1656    15.00394
```

Comment: Do you know the calculation of weighted person time? Is it the sum of the individual person time * weight?

Comment: I don’t see any person-time data in the input. ‘n.risk` is the number of person surviving the the time of an event.

Comment: @IRTFM Assume variable `time`. So how would you e.g. calculate a weighted incidence rate?

Comment: @geek45. Did you edit the question? Is there a [MCVE]

Comment: I see it is actually a new question. Thanks for the tip ;) I thought it would be okay, since the weighted events and n at risk were calculated here